# Как сохранить таблицу из DataGridView в БД (MS Access)?

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, datagridview

Каким образом можно сохранить таблицу, изменённую в DataGridView, в БД?

Отображаю таблицы так:

```
public void refreshTable() {
            string conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=db.mdb";
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM " + 
                comboBox1.Text, connection); //в comboBox1 название таблицы

            connection.Close();

            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(dataSet);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
            adapter.Update(dataSet);
        }
```

Везде ссылаются на эту статью: http://tech.pro/tutorial/664/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-database

Но я никак не пойму. Взял код оттуда:

```
private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            string conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=db.mdb";
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + 
                comboBox1.Text, connection);

            BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
            DataTable dTable = new DataTable();

            adapter.Fill(dTable);
            bSource.DataSource = dTable;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;

            adapter.Update(dTable);
        }
```

Но он только выводит исходную таблицу из БД (что довольно очевидно). Что мне следует изменить в этом методе?

Примерно так выглядит добавление строк в таблицу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После вызова метода через нажатие кнопки, 3 новые строки исчезают и, соответственно, не попадают в БД.

Обновление: кроме того, если я ввожу что-нибудь недопустимое (буквы в качестве ключа или даты), то получаю исключение, при вызове saveButton_Click.

Обновление: добавил в начале метода записи в БД:

```
    connection.Open();
    adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM dataGridView1", connection);
    adapter.UpdateCommand = cBuilder.GetUpdateCommand(true);
    adapter.InsertCommand = cBuilder.GetInsertCommand(true);
    connection.Close();
```

Теперь при выполнении строки `adapter.UpdateCommand = cBuilder.GetUpdateCommand(true);` получаю ошибку о том, что требуется инициализировать свойство DataAdapter.SelectCommand. Хотя я, вроде как, прямо перед этим её инициализировал.

Comment: После запроса не обновляются данные ? Или я не так понял

Comment: После того, как выполню saveButton_Click, таблица в окне обновляется. При этом всё, что я там менял и добавлял сбрасывается. Т.е., всё по новой читается из БД.

Comment: Покажите как Вы изменяете свои данные, потому что в примере у Вас типичная выборка и все должно работать хорошо.

Comment: У вас в коде задана только SelectCommand (в конструкторе адаптера). А нужно также определить InsertCommand, DeleteCommand, UpdateCommand, чтобы работали соответствующие возможности. Смотрите, например, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, что-то не соображу, как их правильно задавать. Если kxxko не поможет, попробую получше разобраться.

Comment: @kxxko, например, есть таблица со столбцами с типами: ключ, текст, текст. В новой строке добавляю приемлемые значения в каждой ячейке и запускаю метод. Про результат уже писал.

Comment: @kxxko, добавил скриншот для наглядности.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не дам полного ответа, так как очень давно не работал с winforms, но навскидку у вас в коде сразу две ошибки:

1. Вы создаете новый адаптер каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку, таким
   образом затирая все свои изменения, по уму этот код нужно перенести
   в Window_Load().
2. При создании адаптера создается только SelectCommand, а для связи с
   источником нужны еще UpdateCommand, InsertCommand и DeleteCommand.
   Их надо, либо создать ручками, либо если таблица не содержит связей
   с другими таблицами, можно воспользоваться [OleDbCommandBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommandbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

UPD:

```
// должна быть для конкретного адаптера выполнена команда Fill(...)
OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);

adapter.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand();
... // прочие команды
```

Как то так, но я с адаптерами я не работал уже очень давно, поэтому вам лучше почитать, [например здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms254953%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), правда там не OleDb*, но в принципе все аналогично.

UPD #2:

Добавлять команды в адаптер вы должны тоже в Window_Load сразу после

```
adapter.Fill(dTable);
```

Эта функция должна быть выполнена обязательно ДО, что бы адаптер смог получить схему для которой создает команды.

Насчет ошибки при вводе некорректных данных, абсолютно правильное поведение программы, поищите здесь на сайте были уже вопросы о валидации и инжекции кода , в общем это отдельная большая тема.

UPD #3:

Судя по сообщению, видимо нет. Там где вы делаете Update, поставте точку отладчика и посмотрите, чему равен InsertCommand, возможно вы в разных функциях используете разные адаптеры. Надо: сделать поле формы, в Window_Load - проинициализировать его, в Button_Click - вызвать функцию Update. А вы похоже в просто закинули ваш код в Window_Load - при выходе из которого адаптер просто уничтожается.

Ваш код должен выглядеть как то так:

```
public FormExemple : Form
{
    protected string conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=db.mdb";
    protected OleDbConnection connection;
    protected OleDbDataAdapter adapter;
    ....

    Window_Load()
    {
        connection = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
        ...
        adapter.Fill(dTable);

        cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
        adapter.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand();
        ...
    }

    Button_Click()
    {
        ...
        adapter.Update(dTable)
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Первое поправил. А вот со вторым небольшая проблема. Не подскажешь, как в таком случае составлять команды UpdateCommand, InsertCommand и DeleteCommand (или хотя бы, что гуглить)? По примерам с MSDN не до конца понял.

Comment: Взгляните, пожалуйста на ещё одно дополнение в конце вопроса.

Comment: Записал в Form1_Load. "Для элемента Update требуется действительный InsertCommand при передаче коллекции DataRow с новыми строками". Видимо, это связано с тем, что таблица имеет связь с другой?

Comment: Ты прав, в нужный момент оказывается объявлен только SelectCommand.